# adding weight edge to Network graph in Python

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a large dataframe(df) with Weight ,Source Node, target columns.

| SourceNode | target | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 176890 | 657826 | 201 |
| 136578 | 589231 | 300 |
| 143873 | 457139 | 50 |
| 134589 | 892147 | 550 |
| 198345 | 678931 | 350 |
| 112443 | 525188 | 600 |
| 336128 | 689313 | 1500 |

Source node and target column are object and weight is int data type.
I am trying to create a network graph which shows the connectivity from source node to target column (unidirect) and the edge need to reflect the weight value( like by stronger bigger connection).

This is the code I am using :

```
import networkx as nx


G= nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df_new, source = 'SourceNode', target='target' , edge_attr= 'Weight')

edges = G.edges.data()

pos = nx.kamada_kawai_layout(G)
edge_width = [e[2]['Weight'] for e in edges]
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True) # draw nodes (and edges!)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=pos, width=edge_width)
```

I getting odd graph that everything is black.
I am very new to visualization in pandas. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Try dividing the `edge_width` by 1000 (or some other large-ish) number: `edge_width = [e[2]['Weight']/1000 for e in edges]`.  The default width is 1.0, so your largest line is 1500 times wider than that, which likely results in the lines filling up the entire area of your plot.

Comment: Thanks that worked. However , since I have large dataframe how can I make this graph spread in larger space?

Comment: Since I have large dataframe I tried spring_layout instead of kamada_kawai_layout. However it did not give me the graph when I replace the kamada_kawai_layout with spring_layout. Do you know how can I just change the source node color ?

Comment: I often use [circular_layout](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.circular_layout.html) at least to start with to spread the nodes out as far as possible.  It can get cluttered around the edges if there are too many nodes though.

Comment: If you're really having trouble with the spring_layout, I'd encourage you to post it as a new question.  One thing to check though would be printing out the `pos` dictionary to ensure that each node is assigned a location.  Or is no plot showing up at all?

Comment: To change node color, you can pass in an array of colors equal in length to the number of nodes to assign colors to the nodes.  If you dig through `[networkx]` tagged questions, you'll likely find quite a few answers that would be helpful for you.